# Methods in classes in C#

Tags: c#, class, methods, quartz.net

I have a number of different clases located in a class library in my project. I am using Quartz.NET (a scheduling system) to schedule and load jobs, and the actual job execution is done in these class libraries. I plan to have many types of job types, and each one will have their own class for execution in the class library.

An issue I have is that I can't nest methods in these classes. For example, here is my class:

```
public class FTPtoFTP : IJob
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HTTPtoFTP));

    public FTPtoFTP()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {          
        //Code that executes, the variable context allows me to access the job information
    }
}
```

If I try to put a method in the execution part of the class, such as...

```
 string[] GetFileList()
 { 
    //Code for getting file list
 }
```

It expects the end of the execution method before my GetFileList one begins, and also doesn't let me access the context variable which I need.

I hope this makes sense, thanks again - you guys rule

Comment: where are you trying to put the string[] GetFileList function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood how class code works?

`GetFileList()` doesn't execute just because you have placed it in the class after `Execute()` - you have to actually call it, like this:

```
public class FTPtoFTP : IJob
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HTTPtoFTP));

    public FTPtoFTP()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        string[] files = GetFileList();

        //Code that executes, the variable context allows me to access the job information
    }

    string[] GetFileList()
    { 
        //Code for getting file list
    }
}
```

or have i totally misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't nest methods. Here are a couple of approaches you can use instead:

- You can create [anonymous functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx) inside methods and call them in a similar way to calling a method.
- You can promote local variables in one method to member fields and then you can access them from both methods.

Comment: ... or you can just pass the context variable into a private `GetFileList` as a parameter!

Answer (score 1):

You could use lambda expressions:

```
public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context) 
{ 

    Func<string[]> getFileList = () => { /*access context and return an array */};

    string[] strings = getFileList();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the results from the `GetFileList` function and use them in `Execute`?
If so, then just try this:

```
public class FTPtoFTP : IJob
{
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HTTPtoFTP));

    public FTPtoFTP()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //Code that executes, the variable context allows me to access the job information
        string[] file_list = GetFileList();
        // use file_list
    }

    private string[] GetFileList()
    { 
       //Code for getting file list
       return list_of_strings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Execute` is a virtual method, its not a space to declare additional methods, inside you're meant to place any logic for the job, its not a namespace to declare new methods. If you want to use methodised logic, just declare them within the class definition and call them from the execute function.

```
public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
{

    mymethod1();
    mymethod2();
}

private void mymethod1()
{}

private void mymethod2()
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to get the file list based on some context information - in this case just add a parameter to the `GetFileList` method and pass it from `Execute`:

```
public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
{
    string[] fileList = this.GetFileList(context);
    ...
}

private string[] GetFileList(JobExecutionContext) { ... }
```